# Get a Result from Database, convert XML, repeat for all results

Tags: php, xml, loops, for-loop, xml-parsing

Php Code:

```
## Loop through results from mysql
try{
    #connection string
        // $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=wudb',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=wudb','root','toshiba1',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $q = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT FW_ArtSrcLink FROM FW_ArtSrc WHERE OneSet=1 and leagID=20");
    #call stored proc
        $q->execute();
    #get the rows into an array
        $result = $q->fetchAll();
        $newsStory = array();
    foreach($result as $r){
    ## gets url from database as outlined above.
        $xmlUrl = $r['FW_ArtSrcLink'];
    #Loads the url above into XML    
        $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
        # -> Setup XML
        $newsStory[] = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
    }
```

I am trying to get a link provided by my database aka `$xmlUrl`

Then extract the XML from the url with `$ConvertToXml`, then do this for each result.

Then finally output the result.

What am I doing wrong here? Currently it's getting ONLY the first result from each result and outputting it. I want to get them all